# Provider component does not update when placed at the top level of an app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I place my Provider component at the highest level of the application it does not update with the correct state. I did try placing console logs within it which do not show up either.
The code looks like this:

```
const Root = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('My App', () => Root);
```

It is immediately consumed in the child component "App" which shows it has a value of null.

If I remove it from the Root function shown above and instead nest it inside another component it works as intended.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <PrimaryComponent/>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

**PrimaryComponent: **

```
export const PrimaryComponent = () => {
    const authContext = useAuthContext();

    //... Other code
}
```

For reference:

```
export const useAuthContext = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

In both instances I used a useContext(AuthContext) but only the later works.
I don't understand why when it is placed as the first thing React must render it does not trigger anything but when nested it works as normal.

Edit: Added the code where i use the context

```
const PrimaryComponent = () => {
const authContext = useAuthContext();
    const navigation = useNavigation<any>();


    useEffect(() => {
        intialize();
    }, []);


    useEffect(()=> {
        if(!authContext.authState.authenticated){
            if(navigation.canGoBack()){
                navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
            }
        }
    },[authContext]);


    const intialize = async () => {

        try {
            const value: any = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token');
            const authData = JSON.parse(value);
            if (authData === null || authData.accessToken === null) {
                navigation.navigate('login');
                return;
            }
            // Update state
            authContext.setAuthState({
                authenticated: authData.accessToken !== null,
            });

            // By default navigate to the home screen
            navigation.navigate('home');

            setStatus('success');
        } catch (error) {
            setStatus('error');
            console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);
            authContext.setAuthState({
                authenticated: false,
            });
        }

    }


    if (authContext.authenticated) {
       return <UserNavigation />;
    } else {
       return <GenericNavigation />
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work. How do you update the state?

Comment: The issue you're encountering is likely caused by the fact that AppRegistry.registerComponent is a method from the React Native library, and it behaves differently than a regular React application.

When AppRegistry.registerComponent is called, it creates a new root component for your application, and any components passed to it will be rendered as the top-level components in the app. This means that the AuthProvider component will be rendered as a top-level component, but it's not getting re-rendered when the state changes.

Comment: @NathanHall I dont quite understand this. Does it block the Provider from setting its own state?. While the value I kept getting was Null. I do pass some values to the provider instead of the default null. This never reaches any consumers though.

Comment: @Konrad the context has a useState function. I call authContext.setState(...)

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: @Konrad I updated the post with how i use it